# Error in getting Active subscriber count from Sendy API

Tags: php, post, sendy

While trying to fetch the active subscriber count from Sendy API, I am getting following error 
[image]

The `POST` request looks like this:

```
http://my-sandy-Installation/api/subscribers/active-subscriber-count.php
```

In header: `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

In Body:

```
api_key= mykey
list_id= mylistid
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: This question shows no own research effort at all. Did you at least have a look at https://sendy.co/get-started ?

Comment: Yes @digijay, I did all the research at my end. I have the latest version of sendy i.e 3.1.1. I have a total 10 brands in my sendy and several lists are there. Now I want to fetch the subscribers count for each list using api. I have also gone through the api documentation as well as explored the sendy's support forum for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$boolean = 'true';
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
    'email' => $email,
    'api_key'=>'your api_key',
    'list' => 'Your List id',
    'boolean' => 'true'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST', 'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content' => $postdata));
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($your_installation_url.'/subscribe', false, $context);
```

Comment: Please add some detail, like what you have done that solve the problem.